# What can be used to get rid of hard water spots?

Tags: maintenance, paint-clearcoat, carwash

Most water spot removers available on Amazon or automotive stores are just fine abrasives which remove a small amount of your car's clearcoat every time you use them.

I'm looking for a chemical/product which can dissolve the water spots made out of limestone, chalk and gypsum.

Any acids suggested should not be strong enough to damage clearcoat (diluted), should not be abrasive. Obviously I will not leave it on my car for very long, just apply, maybe rub around and rinse off with water.

I've not had any success with vinegar

Comment: Are the spots the result of washing the vehicle with hard domestic water or from rainfall?

Comment: Try some vinegar.

Comment: @mikes it's a combination of both. Mostly washing though.